# Room - RxJava : getByName() query not working

Tags: android-room, rx-java2

I'm using Room for persistence in my app. I have a `Player` table, which has a `name` and `matchesPlayed` column.

When a match is played by a Player, I would like to increment `matchesPlayed` if it was played by an existing Player, or create a new Player otherwise. In order to determine this, I created a SQL query `getPlayerByName(name: String)` which should return us the Player if it exists. When I run the query in the Database Inspector in Android Studio, everything works fine. However, when I run the same query in the app, it fails. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

##### Player.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "players")
data class Player(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "matches_played") val matchesPlayed: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "matches_won") val matchesWon: String
)
```

##### PlayerDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface PlayerDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $PLAYER_TABLE_NAME")
    fun getAll(): Single<List<Player>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $PLAYER_TABLE_NAME WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1")
    fun getPlayerByName(name: String): Maybe<Player>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(player: Player): Completable
}
```

##### PlayerViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlayerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val playerRepository: PlayerRepositoryImpl
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    private fun findAndInsertPlayer(
        playerName: String,
        playerWon: Boolean
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val increment = if (playerWon) 1 else 0
            playerRepository.getPlayerByName(playerName)
                .subscribe(
                    { player ->
                        // Handle Success
                    },
                    {
                        // Somehow, this block always gets called
                    }
                )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? What is the exception stacktrace? Why haven't you shared these information in the first place?